# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to find whether a text in a table of a page using Watir.

Parts of the table:

```
<td class="left"><a class="xoName" name="Basket Case" href="View.aspx?contactID=2D67AD97-7486-4DB9-AB83-A2C76B116618">Basket Case</a>
</td>
<td class="left" onclick="parent.location='View.aspx?contactID=2D67AD97-7486-4DB9-AB83- A2C76B116618'">shop@basketcase.co</td>
```

and here is the code that I used:

```
if b1.text(:xpath =>'/html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a').include?(@fullName)
  puts "  Test Passed. Found the contact: " + @fullName + ".  Actual Results match Expected Results."
else
  puts "  Test Failed! Could not find contact: " + @fullName
end
```

and the error message that I got:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.4/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:94:in `text': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby192/scripts/watir/highrise-welli.rb:71:in `<main>'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Um I'm having trouble parsing this: "I am trying to find whether a text in a table of a page using Watir."  to understand what you want to do..  you are trying to find whether text WHAT? exists??

Comment: And `highrise-welli.rb:71` is?

Comment: Such long xpath is always a bad idea: `/html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a`

Comment: I don't generally downvote questions, but the inability to understand what is being asked based on phrasing, and complete lack of any response by the user to any of the requests made in comments, or to edit their question to make it clearer is causing me to do so in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I generally do all I can to avoid using xpath as it is slow tends to create unreadable code and getting the paths right is tricky.

consider creating a regular expression and using that to specify the element you are looking for along with the .exists method.  This presumes you know how to identify the table you are searching, and the text is contained in a single cell in the table.

```
targettext = Regexp.new(@fullName)
if browser.table(:how, 'what').cell(:text, targettext).exists? 
  puts 'success message'
else
  puts 'fail message'
end
```

If you are not reading in @fullname and it can be hard coded, then you can skip a step and just specify inline

```
  if browser.table(:how, 'what').cell(:text, /textyouaresearchingfor/).exists?
```

Comment: And for what it's worth, I agree totally with Jason's suggestion to use Rspec or Cucumber and their .should method as a means of asserting a given condition exists.  I didn't get into that since it seemed you were having enough trouble with how to identify elements, and well 'one thing at a time'.

Answer (score 0):

For the example/error pair, the text method does not take args.

```
in `text': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

As soon as it says "arguments", look at the method you are using.

Additionally, using rspec gem, means writing less code. Then you can do this (see below)  instead of rolling your own error handling.

```
targettext = Regexp.new(@fullName)
browser.table(:how, 'what').cell(:text, targettext).exists?.should == true
```

Now you only have two lines of code.